# How to block the HTTP request to a particular IP in libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm using libcurl(http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to fire HTTP request. 
I want to block the request to a particular IP address once the FQDN resolved to IP address.

How and where I can block the request for particular IP address?

Comment: You can resolve FQDN to IP before send HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, I can but where exactly I should resolve before HTTP request to server  and In case FQDN is already resolved, can I get IP from cache maintained by libcurl?

Comment: Do not send HTTP request if your know IP address. Can you provide an example? I think I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libcurl itself has no block-this-IP-functionality built-in. But it does provide you with the building blocks for you to build your own!

Use [CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.html) and have your callback do the address check, and return failure if the "bad" address is used and otherwise you call the normal socket() function.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I used this function to get the control before creating socket, However I'm not able to retrieve the IP address from the data received in this call back function. The strcut receives in this callback function is: struct curl_sockaddr *addres

Comment: Yes, and that struct contains a "struct sockaddr" which holds the address. See http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html

Comment: I was able to block the request going to a particular IP and return "CURL_SOCKET_BAD" from CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION function, however that results into "CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT" in my program and I'm not able to figure it out which request is blocked and reason for blocking. Is there any other return code that libcurl can return on such blocking request?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html) to find out the IP address of the FQDN. Use that address to determine whether to submit a curl request or not.